# Where does energy go when it is used against itself?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws

Suppose a ufo can convert fuel into kinetic energy with 100% efficiency. The ufo travels forwards some distance and then back in the vacuum of space. The ufo stops and has returned to it's original location and original speed. Obviously, the ufo has expended energy in this situation, but otherwise, the system seems to have remained unchanged. Conservation of energy says this is impossible, so where did the energy in the fuel energy go?

Comment: by what mechanism does it stop in a vacuum?

Comment: The mechanism by which the ufo moves is that it takes a particular object and pushes it in the opposite direction of where it wants to go

Comment: then you have your answer - the energy is imparted into that particular object.

Comment: However, when the ufo is moving back towards its original location, it also moves the object back to its original location as well, so there was no work done to the object

Comment: @PatrickFeng Both objects now have the same energy as when you started.  No issue.  The problem is that you _need_ the second object to do this, that seems to be your confusion.

Comment: that's actually not too dissimilar from the dynamics of two objects orbiting each other

Comment: @JMac I'm sorry, I don't seem to understand. Could you explain to me what the problem is with needing the second object?

Comment: @PatrickFeng It just means that you actually do have somewhere that the energy is going.  Either on another object, or dissipated through space via some mechanism (which requires some form of _something_).  With the second object, both systems move a bunch; but in the end; they both end up stationary in the exact same position.  No change in _net_ energy, it just transferred between objects.

Answer (score 2):

An object cannot change its velocity without changing its momentum, and momentum is conserved.  This implies that the UFO must have either ejected some sort of mass, in which case this ejected mass is in a different state than at the beginning;  or the UFO must be interacting with some background field, in which case the external field will be in a different state after the manipulations have been done.  In neither case can the system viewed as a whole return to the initial configuration.

Comment: Ok, but what if the mass ejected does not leave the picture, but is instead (with energy) also returned to its original state?

Comment: @PatrickFeng: The same argument applies to the ejected mass:  how are you going to stop it & return it to the UFO without changing its momentum?

Comment: I can use the fuel to stop the ufo, and the ufo to stop the fuel

Comment: @PatrickFeng:  I'm not so sure you can, at least not without having a step where energy is pretty obviously lost (which is the whole point of your question.)  If you think you've got an idea about how to do it, then I would recommend you ask it as a new question.

Comment: @PatrickFeng Can I use an oven to cook my meal, and use my cooked meal to power my oven?  It's a similar scenario with this situation.